# How to create virtual machine by command "docker-machine create" with windows

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I have a project in Visual Studio 2019. I want to learn Docker and try to deploy my 2 web applications in a swarm.

When i use command
        "docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "stationext" myvm1" 
Docker creates a virtual machine. I can see it in Hyper-V Manager. But this VM is with Linux.

How to create VM by command "docker-machine create" with Windows on board?

Log from creating

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "stationext" myvm3
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(myvm3) Copying C:\Users\Sergii\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\Sergii\.docker\machine\machines\myvm3\boot2docker.iso...
(myvm3) Creating SSH key...
(myvm3) Creating VM...
(myvm3) Using switch "stationext"
(myvm3) Creating VHD
(myvm3) Starting VM...
(myvm3) Waiting for host to start...
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Provisioning with boot2docker...
Copying certs to the local machine directory...
Copying certs to the remote machine...
Setting Docker configuration on the remote daemon...
Checking connection to Docker...
Docker is up and running!
To see how to connect your Docker Client to the Docker Engine running on this virtual machine, run: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker-machine.exe env myvm3
```

[What i see in VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJn6p.png)

Comment: Can you share log from the command that you used to create the docker machine?

Comment: I have added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the behavior is the expected one, don't know where did you see that you will be launching windows OS containers, boot2docker is Linux as you can see on their git:

https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#readme

At the same time, you can see that this is deprecated in favor of Docker for Windows.
For running windows host on docker I think you should have a look at this:

https://www.docker.com/products/windows-containers